# Application Insights Configuration Insanity

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

Most of the following configuration settings have been added by Azure to my .NET 8 web application automagically.

```
APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION
APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING
APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_ENABLESQLQUERYCOLLECTION
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION
DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION
DISABLE_APPINSIGHTS_SDK
IGNORE_APPINSIGHTS_SDK
InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_PreemptSdk
```

Is there a sane way to reorganize, consolidate, or eliminate these?
I have another app service with an identical application, but it contains only a fraction of these items. I have no idea why. To me, this seems out of control.

Comment: Please check the below answer. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

When Application Insights is configured manually in the Web App, based on the installed packages and the configuration in `App Service` = >`Application Insights`, the settings will be added in the App Service.

- I have configured Application Insights from Connected Services.

[image]

- Only     `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` package is included in my `.csproj` file.
- After deployment I don't have any settings added in my Application Environment Variables.

[image]

- Still Iam able to see the basic requests and traces.
- I have Enabled the Application Insights in the App Service.

[image]

- Now, I can see that few settings are added in the Environment Variables based on the Instrument Settings.

[image]

***Environment Settings after Enabling Application Insights:***

[image]

- To log the basic Traces/ Requests you only need Instrumentation Key (`APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`) and Connection String (`APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING`).
- If you don't want any additional traces, you can safely remove those settings or disable from the Application Insights section which is mentioned above.